# how to use role and permission dynamically in laravel

Tags: java, php, laravel, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have tables:

users, roles & permissions.

Pivot tables:

role_user & permission_role.

Models:

User, Role and Permission.

Now what I'd like to achieve is that let's say admin adds new permission in control panel. then the bad thing is I, as a developer, have to get up, open the code and put this newly added permission in middlware of some routes by hand. each time new permission comes into play from admin, I have to add the code by hands.

Is there any way to do all that dynamically so that after admin adds new permission, i don't change anything, i don't add the code and this new permission automatically starts working?

I think this is impossible. so my question is: why do I have to let admin add roles and permissions from control panel at all? I think I should be the one who seeds this permission and roles.

Comment: see this package https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible, but then you would need another table that contains the permissions required for each page. When you have this you can make a global middleware that checks if the user can access the page based on the permissions that are attached to the current page.

Now you can let the admin attach permissions to pages and attach permissions to users, and no code has to be changed when a new permission is created.

Comment: It's a lot of headache. maybe I'll seed permissions and roles. admin can only attach and detach.  what do you think?

Comment: I am using vue.js as a front-end and back-end as laravel API. they are on a different server. so for each api call, vue.js has to pass route name to API. right?

Comment: Thinking about the same to resolve this I think you should use a column in the permission table where you store method and route and check it from another function therefor you can use middleware for this purpose.